# Shortcut to delete something

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

What is the shortcut for deleting an item? On windows, it's just the delete key, which my macbook is lacking.

I know the "mouse-way" of right-clicking a folder and hitting "Move to Trash" but that imho takes too long for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Finder it's  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd> 
If your Mac doesn't have separate Backspace & Delete keys, it's whichever one it does have.
Incidentally, this also works as "Don't Save" if a document hasn't been saved when you close it.

To bypass the Trash & delete immediately, use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd>

& just to complete the set...
To empty the Trash, use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to use "delete" when writing text? I mean like "deleting the character coming after the cursor".

Comment: That really ought to be a new question - but it's Fn [whichever delete/backspace you have] unless you have both, in which case it's just 'the other one'. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question ;)